# DRF- Error when creating a new instance in an M2M through model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have the following two models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=129,
        unique=True,
    )
    user_article = models.ManyToManyField(
        Article,
        through="UserArticle",
    )
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='null')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_id
```

and

```
class Article(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(editable=False, unique=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='article_company_id',
    )
    articleType = models.ForeignKey(
        ArticleType,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='type',
    )    
    date_inserted = models.DateField()    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.uuid
```

which are modeled with a many-to-many relationship, using this through model:

```
class UserArticle(models.Model):    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field='user_id',
                             on_delete=models.PROTECT,)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, to_field='uuid',
                                 on_delete=models.PROTECT,)
    posted_as = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True),)
    post_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "core_user_articles"
```

Here's my view:

```
class BatchUserArticleList(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                        mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                        generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = UserArticle.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BatchUserArticleSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = BatchUserArticleSerializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return response.Response({'Message': 'POST failed',
                                  'Errors': serializer.errors},
                                 status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        self.perform_create(serializer)  # equal to serializer.save()
        return response.Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The problem I'm facing is when I want to POST data, of the following format, in the M2M table:

```
{
    "posted_as": ["news"],
    "post_date": "2020-05-26",
    "user": "jhtpo9jkj4WVQc0000GXk0zkkhv7u",
    "article": [
        "11111111",
        "22222222"
    ]
}
```

The above contains a list of many articles so I used a `custom field` in my `serializer` in order to extract each `article`, create a new `UserArticle` object and insert it, using `bulk_create`, into my M2M table. I think that's the way to go when the incoming data do not map exactly to the DB model, but I might be wrong. So please comment if you see something off with this approach.

Here is the serializer:

```
class BatchUserArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    article= ArticleField(source='*') #custom field

    class Meta:
        model = UserArticle
        fields = ('posted_as', 'post_date', 'user', 'article')

    def validate(self, data):    
        post_date = data['post_date']
        if post_date != date.today():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'post_date: post_date is not valid',
            )
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        post_as = list(map(lambda item: item, validated_data['posted_as']))
        post_date = validated_data['post_date']
        user = validated_data['user']
        list_of_articles = validated_data['article']            
        user_object = User.objects.get(user_id=user)
        articles_objects = list(map(lambda res: Article.objects.get(uuid=res), list_of_articles))    
        user_articles_to_insert = list(map(
            lambda article: UserArticle(
                posted_as=posted_as,
                post_date=post_date,
                article=article,
                user=user_object),
            articles_objects))

        try:
            created_user_articles = UserArticles.objects.bulk_create(user_articles_to_insert)
            for res in created_user_articles:
                res.save()
            return created_user_articles
        except Exception as error:
            raise Exception('Something went wrong: {0}'.format(error))
```

and

```
class ArticleField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        resource_repr = [value.article]
        return resource_repr

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        internal_repr = {
            'article': data
        }
        return internal_repr
```

This seems to work ok as I can see data being correctly inserted in the `UserArticle` table:

```
id | posted_as | post_date | user | article
1  | news      | 2020-05-26 | jhtpo9jkj4WVQc0000GXk0zkkhv7u | 11111111
2  | news      | 2020-05-26 | jhtpo9jkj4WVQc0000GXk0zkkhv7u | 22222222
```

The problem comes when code reaches this line:

```
response.Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

and more specifically, the error I'm getting is:

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `posted_as` on serializer `BatchUserArticleSerializer`.

The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `list` instance. Original exception text was: 'list' object has no attribute 'posted_as'.
```

The original exception error is raised at the `instance = getattr(instance, attr)` line of the `def get_attribute(instance, attrs)` function in the `fields.py` DRF source.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is no reason to call `save` method for each of bulk-created instances.

Second one is reason of exception. You call `create` viewset method. it calling serializers `create` method which must return only one instance (created object). but your serializer returns list `created_user_articles`. List really have no field `posted_as`.

So, there is two ways to fix it.

1. First one is override `create` method in view, to change the way of data representation. For ex. use another serializer for response data:

   ```
   def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
       serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
       created_user_articles = self.perform_create(serializer)

       # use another way to get representation
       response_data = AnotherUserArticleSerializer(created_user_articles, many=True).data
       return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

   def perform_create(self, serializer):
       # add return to get created objects
       return serializer.save()
   ```
2. Second one is return only one instance in `create` method of your serializer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That was indeed the problem! Could you also please give an example of "changing the way of data representation"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @kingJulian  i've added an example

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't understand how this new  `AnotherUserArticleSerializer` will work. I understand tt will serialize the list of the `created_user_articles`  but which `model`will it be based on to?

Comment: @kingJulian your create method in serializer creates an `UserArticles` instanses. So new one serializer should be based on `UserArticles` model. You can use even yet existed `BatchUserArticleSerializer` as "additional" serializer. but do not forget `many=True` arg.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't notice the `many=True` argument in your answer. Thank you.